# Why is there 2 Journey downloads for buying the game?

Tags: journey

I brought Journey for the PS3 the other day and after i went through the checkout and went to download it there was infact 2 downloads, Journey Trail one which was about 500 MB and Journey which was about 100kb.

I am wondering why did i get the Trail for? is the 100kb download just some sort of unlocker and Journey Trail is actually the full game?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The larger download is the game. The smaller download is an update that unlocks the game.

I've seen this pattern with other games: Guacamelee, etc.